# Turn off Protected View in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to extract data from a file ('DatabaseExport.xlsx') that has been generated and newly opened from an intranet site. The file opens in Protected View (yellow banner at top of screen).  I think it's necessary to disable the protected view so that I can extract data from the file.  My VBA is contained in a separate file 'GetAndAnalyseData.xlsm':

```
NameOfNewFile = "ooo"
Do
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit  'This never works first time
        NameOfNewFile = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 14)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If NameOfNewFile = "ooo" Then
        ttt = MsgBox("this should not be possible!", vbOKCancel)
        If ttt = vbCancel Then Stop
    End If
Loop While NameOfNewFile = "ooo"
```

When I run the code:

1. I get a message box saying "this should not be possible!"
2. If I click OK, I keep getting the same messagebox, and the file remains in Protected View.
3. If I click Cancel and then F5 (to continue execution) the loop works as it should (protected view is cancelled, the value of TEMP is set to the filename, the loop exits and the macro continues.

The line where I try to assign a value to NameOfNewFile returns an error if I don't use 'Resume Next':

> Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

I have tried several methods to fix this:

1. Running this line before downloading the file, and also immediately before attempting to turn off Protected View, but still the behaviour is the same.

   ```
   Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
   ```
2. Making the folder (where the downloaded file is stored) into a trusted location, but this is not allowed by my user settings.
3. Unchecking the "Enable Protected View for files originating from the Internet" box in Trust Center, but with this box unchecked I can't open the file.
4. Inserting this code (but the "Set wbPV line" causes Run-time error '424': Object Required):

   ```
   Dim wbPV As Workbook
   If Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then
       Set wbPV = ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
   End If
   ```

How can I turn off Protected View programmatically for this type of downloaded file?  Or is there some other way to get data out of the file?

Comment: Have you tried AcativeSheet.Unprotect

Comment: `been generated and newly opened` How is this happening? Can you get it to save instead of open which should eliminate your issue?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I have tried Activesheet.Unprotect and gives a similar error message, and if I put it within the 'on error' section, it gives the same behaviour as the lines that are already in there.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, Activesheet.Unprotect gives error 91. 

To answer @findwindow, the file is generated by a corporate intranet site. 

Saving rather than opening is a good workaround (if I save in a manually specified location rather than the default Downloads folder, the `ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit` command works first time).

Comment: If you move `NameOfNewFile = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 14)` to *after* `On Error GoTo 0`, do you get an error message?  I **strongly** suspect that you will.  Not guaranteed to work, but try adding `DoEvents` after the `Do`?

Answer (score 1):

Option Explicit

```
    Sub Auto_edit_Workbooks()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wbPV As ProtectedViewWindow
        If Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then
            For Each wbPV In Application.ProtectedViewWindows
            wbPV.Activate
            Set wb = wbPV.Edit()
            Next wbPV
        Else
        End If
    Set wb = Nothing
    End Sub
```